# Profiling WebGL with chrome://tracing

Tags: html, google-chrome, opengl-es, profiling, webgl

I'm trying to improve FPS of my deferred renderer and so I stumbled on chrome://tracing ([here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool) and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/games/abouttracing/)). I added `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` for every layer I render. You can see them here:

[image: detail of my trace points]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAez9.jpg

My trace points are the topmost items starting with `node/...`, together, they run for about 2ms. All is done within these two milliseconds, all the `gl*` calls. My current FPS is around 38 FPS, one frame account for around 28ms. Now another, zoomed out picture with GPU process:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p1sD.jpg

You can still see the trace points there, tiny bars at the top. Strangely, Chrome renders two frames very quickly, then runs this mysterious `DoSwapBuffers` / `Onscreen` tasks that halts the rendering for about 25ms, plus the `MakeCurrent` tasks that overlaps with the second (as in the two fast consecutive frames) frame, that takes 15ms.

It seems to me that Chrome is deferring all the WebGL tasks for later, making it impossible to make any kind of profiling. But that's just my guess. What to do with this and how can I profile my WebGL code?

Comment: Are you using VSYNC by any chance? This almost sounds like normal behavior in such a case. The actual frame finishes in a fraction of the time that it takes for the VBLANK interval to come around, and then after the swap-chain is full `SwapBuffers (...)` causes blocking.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Chrome's default is to use VSYNC, however I have it disabled in chrome://flags

Answer (score 0):

As the GPU is running independent of the main JS thread, it is not synchronized to the JS activity as long as there is no direct feedback of the rendered data into the JS context. So issuing any WebGL command does not block JavaScript from going on, and the frame is only presented if the GPU has finished all operations issued by JS.

So it is impossible to see the actual computation time for any WebGL operation in this trace.

There is however a simple trick: Synchronize the JS thread by pulling some rendering-dependent data back into the JS world. The easiest thing to do so is to render some pixels of every intermediate texture to the 3D canvas, and this canvas  into a 2D canvas by the 2D context `drawImage` method (and just to be sure access this canvas by `ctx.getImageData()`). This method is quite slow and will add *some* time, by also make all WebGL draw operations visible to profiling / tracing.
Beware that this may also skew the results to some extend as everything will be forced to compute in-order and the GPU driver cannot optiimize independent draw to operations to interleave each other.